# Android Studio setting the background color for Field requires API level xx

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, there is a background color effect for some fields(e.g. View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE, View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN).

Example:

[image: Enter image description]

When I put the mouse on it, the pop-up is displayed telling me that "Field requires API level xx (current min is xx)". 
It's very usuful. So I can make some conditions for each Android OS version.

I've remove the effect by mistake. but I don't remember what item on setting is for it. 
So, I really want to revive the background-color effect and the message pop-up for "Field requires API level xx (current min is xx).

Naturally, I can revive it by re-installing Android Stuido or resetting the IDE Setting to Default. 
But I already made alot of changes on Android Studio Setting. and I don't want to lose it..

I've never found a item to revive it in Android Studio's setting.
please help me

Comment: Only a hacky idea, so not as answer: You can disable all code inspections (or only the ones of the kind which you have right now) which should remove that background coloring however that is probably no what you want to take in as side-effect.

Comment: Actually, I restore the background-color effect and pop-up. because I removed them by mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press Alt+Enter you'll see that it suggests `@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")` to disable the warning.

Doing a search for "inline" in the IntelliJ/Android Studio settings leads to this:

[image]

Go to `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Android > Lint > Correctness > Using inlined constants on older versions` (you can also search to find it). Here you can disable it by unchecking it; remember to click apply or OK to save it.

For reference, [it's in Android Studio as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4KAE.png) under the same location.

For changing the background color, click the severity spinner and click "edit severities". Click warning or create a new severity and set the color (the settings should make it easy to see). Reenabling is in the same location by checking the box or changing the severity level to warning or error for that matter.

<sub>Checked in IntelliJ 2018.1 and Android Studio 3.1.2. It might not be present in older versions of either IDE, or it might be in different locations.</sub>

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to make the background-color effect for it. because I've remove the effect by mistake. but I don't remember what item on setting is for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are wasy to disable inspection. But **Disabling inspection is not recommended**, because

- **You will not get further important suggestion** about some version requirements. (like if particular method require 21 and you are targeting API 15, then it does not sound good to have that method.)
- If some user is running your app on 16 version then your code will crash, because it was not added in that API level.

Got that?

**Solution:**

1.You can check API level in your code. for that only press `alt + enter` on that suggestion you said, and accept changes. It will generate a code like this.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {}
```

2.You can increase your minimum sdk level from app level `build.gradle`

```
  defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        ...
        }
```

Comment: Whether disabling it is recommended or not isn't the question. There are a ton of reasons why you'd need to disable inspections, because the IDE can be wrong. Or it's an inspection that's not important. OP asked how to disable it, not about how to avoid it.

Comment: If we misguide freshers, it's our fault. We should always show them correct way.

Comment: yes, IDEs are wrong. As a random example, I have some code written in Kotlin where there is an instance marked as nullable that's initialized at a specific point. The IDE highlights it could be null, but it can't be because it's never made null. The IDE *can* be wrong, and if it is, disabling the inspection is the only way. Obviously, this means if there *is* something wrong, the app will crash. This is a risk that comes with disabling inspections, but if the IDE is wrong, it's worth it. So to repeat my first comment; OP asks for disabling it, not avoiding it.

Comment: First of all if you are having some IDE issue then just restart it. But you can not disable the inspection just because it is giving you worthy suggestions? Does this sound good. What about some classes which were not available before API x. Will you not check or use compatible method?

Comment: Someday you will disable all suggestion cause just some personal issues and will lead making your android studio to notepad.

Comment: Disabling inspections means you know you actively know what you're doing; as in you acknowledge the fact that it will not warn you or give you errors. And new classes do not run under InlinedApi, it uses NewApi. Disabling InlinedApi won't affect the use of new APIs. And NewApi is an error in the IDE, while InlinedApi is a warning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171877/discussion-between-zoe-and-khemraj).

Comment: Thank you.. but do you know the item to restore this on Android Studio Setting?

Comment: @BKK did not get you. Can you be more specific?